# get dump using nanodump and parse in mimikatz

Tags: c, visual-studio

i am using [nanodump](https://github.com/helpsystems/nanodump) for dumping lsass.exe.
everything is ok, but when i get to mimikatz by following command,got error:

`mimikatz.exe "sekurlsa::minidump <path/to/dumpfile>" "sekurlsa::logonPasswords full" exit`

mimikatz error:
`ERROR kuhl_m_sekurlsa_acquireLSA ; Memory opening`

i use "x64 nanodump ssp dll", and AddSecurityPackage winapi for attaching to lsass

when i was testing all way's, detect that nanodump specified dump file size(default=>report.docx),is different from procmon.exe Full and Mini dump output.

my test:

procmon full = 71 MB
procmon mini = 1.6 MB

nanodump = 11 MB

what can i do for dump by nanodump,compatible with mimikatz::logonpasswords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was for invalid file signature dumped by nano ssp module, this probled solved by this command:

```
[nano git source]/scripts/restore_signature.exe
```